# simplexml_load_file() [function.simplexml-load-file]: Start tag expected, '<' not found in

Tags: php, xml, rss

I am using `simplexml_load_file` to load the BBC Weather RSS feed and it randomly gives the following error:

```
Warning: simplexml_load_file() [function.simplexml-load-file]:  :1: parser error : Start tag expected, '<' not found in
```

It seems to fail randomly. My code is not dynamically changing so I can't figure out why it fails only sometimes.

If I grab the rss file that "supposedly" has the missing `<` tag and store it on my computer and point the `simplexml_load_file` to that location it works fine.

Any advice most appreciated as this minor issue is driving me mad.

Comment: Can you show us some code in order for us to be able to help you?

Comment: Show your code @Mark Blackham

Comment: $url = "http://open.live.bbc.co.uk/weather/feeds/en/2656173/3dayforecast.rss";
$xml = simplexml_load_file($url);

Comment: @NathanSrivi                                                        $url = "http://open.live.bbc.co.uk/weather/feeds/en/2656173/3dayforecast.rss";
$xml = simplexml_load_file($url);

Comment: @Mark Blackham simplexml_load_file some times not working in localhost. but working in live server. i am using curl for all times. check my answer

Answer (score 0):

Try this [Curl](http://no.php.net/curl)

```
<?php
$k = 'http://open.live.bbc.co.uk/weather/feeds/en/2656173/3dayforecast.rss';
$ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $k);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    $rss = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    $xml = simplexml_load_string($rss, 'SimpleXMLElement', LIBXML_NOCDATA);
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($xml);
    echo "</pre>";

    // if you want all items

    //$xml->channel->item item is a array

    //So 

    foreach($$xml->channel->item as $item){
    echo $item->title;  // you can get all results here
    }
?>
```

Comment: @Mark Blackham if my answer is correct dont forget to check the tick mark.

Comment: I have sometimes see the same error as Mark, and I was already using Curl to load my xml. I think the problem must be that sometimes the feed is malformed. I've solved it by putting an @ infront of my simplexml_load_string :)