# RSS Feed - Failed loading XML Start tag expected, '<' not found

Tags: php, rss, rss-reader, simplexml

I'm trying to get a RSS feed from [Sotheby's website](https://investor.shareholder.com/bid/rss.cfm) working on my site using a standard PHP reader function that uses simplexml_load_file and a loop but it doesn't work properly. When I plug in this code I get a 'Failed loading XML Start tag expected, '<' not found' error.'

```
<?php
$url = 'http://apps.shareholder.com/rss/rss.aspx?channels=2908&companyid=BID&sh_auth=1184301877%2E0%2E0%2E42356%2E14434fd9e3fcb0c832c884fe9ff36e31';
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$sxe = simplexml_load_string($url);
if ($sxe === false) {
echo "Failed loading XML\n";
foreach(libxml_get_errors() as $error) {
echo "\t", $error->message;
}
}
print_r($rss);
?>
```

I've tried using curl from [this posting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18616890/simplexml-load-file-function-simplexml-load-file-start-tag-expected-no) but it just prints an empty pre tag.

Here's the reader PHP code I was using...

```
<?php
$url = "http://apps.shareholder.com/rss/rss.aspx?channels=2908&companyid=BID&sh_auth=1184301877%2E0%2E0%2E42356%2E14434fd9e3fcb0c832c884fe9ff36e31";
$rss = simplexml_load_file($url);
if($rss)
{
$items = $rss->channel->item;
foreach($items as $item)

{
if($i==5) break;    
$title = $item->title;
$link = $item->link;
$published_on = $item->pubDate;
$description = $item->description;?>
<hr>                            
<div class="news-story">
<?php 
echo '<h3><a href="'.$link.'">'.$title.'</a></h3>';
echo '<span class="news-date">('.$published_on.')</span>';
?>

</div>
<?php
$i++;      
}
}
?>
```

And here is the [Sotheby's news RSS feed](http://apps.shareholder.com/rss/rss.aspx?channels=2908&companyid=BID&sh_auth=1184301877%2E0%2E0%2E42356%2E14434fd9e3fcb0c832c884fe9ff36e31) I was trying to pull from.

Any help or suggestions would be very helpful. Thanks!

EDIT

Thanks The fourth bird for referring to this [Stack question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8693043/using-simplexml-to-load-remote-url), it worked last night, but when I check today it stopped working...

```
<?php
$context  = stream_context_create(array('http' => array('header' => 'Accept: application/xml')));
$url = 'http://apps.shareholder.com/rss/rss.aspx?channels=2908&companyid=BID&sh_auth=1184301877%2E0%2E0%2E42356%2E14434fd9e3fcb0c832c884fe9ff36e31';

$xml = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
$xml = simplexml_load_string($xml);
print_r($xml);
?>
```

These are some of the errors I'm getting in my MAMP php_error.log:

[18-Dec-2015 07:46:41 America/New_York] PHP Warning:  simplexml_load_string(): </html> in (*my site root folder)

[18-Dec-2015 07:46:41 America/New_York] PHP Warning:  simplexml_load_string():        ^ in (*my site root folder)

[18-Dec-2015 07:46:41 America/New_York] PHP Warning:  simplexml_load_string(): Entity: line 85: parser error : Premature end of data in tag html line 2 in  (*my site root folder)

And they basically repeat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first code block you provided, you are using [simplexml_load_string](http://php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-load-string.php).

The manual describes the first parameter as:

> A well-formed XML string

In you code you are passing a url. If you want to use `simplexml_load_string`, the answer to this question might help you:
[Using SimpleXML to load remote URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8693043/using-simplexml-to-load-remote-url)

In the second code block you provided, you use [simplexml_load_file](http://php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-load-file.php)

The manual describes the first parameter as:

> Path to the XML file

If I try the code in the second code block it is showing me the data from RSS Feed, it only gives me this PHP Notice:

> PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: i

Comment: The link you send me worked great! I'm having a little trouble pulling certain elements from the string though. I don't want to display all the news feed xml content just the title, link and date. Would it be better to use simplexml_load_string on a separate php file, then use simplexml_load_file on that separate php file to pull the content?

Comment: Do you get the expected response when you for example load the rss url in the browser?
If I use the code from your edit then I see the data in the print_r.

Answer (score 0):

It was actually the last part of the URL that was causing it to break when parsing the XML data. When I removed '&sh_auth=1184301877%2E0%2E0%2E42356%2E14434fd9e3fcb0c832c884fe9ff36e31' from the url the initial code block I posted using simplexml_load_file() worked perfectly and hasn't broken since. Thanks for the help The forth bird!